# Como customizar la respuesta de un método create en serializer de Django?

Tags: python, json, api, djangorestframework, serialización

necesito enviar una lista de "estados" y que se creen tantos registros como estados haya en la lista. Como respuesta se debe mostrar el id y el nombre de cada estado.
Ejemplo. Debo enviar esto:

```json
"states": ["Active", "Inactive", "Deleted"]
```

Y debe devolverme lo siguiente:

```json
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "state": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "state": "Inactive"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "state": "Deleted"
        }
]
```

Cuando paso una lista de "estados" por parámetro en un método `POST` de mi vista, los registros se generan exitosamente. Pero no me devuelve absolutamente nada. Me doy cuenta que los registros se crearon cuando los pido luego con un metodo GET. Este es el serializer con el metodo `create()`

```
class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """State serializer."""
    states = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.CharField(max_length=45),
        write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        """State Meta class."""
        model = State
        fields = ['id', 'state', 'states']
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'state']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create State method.

        Takes the states list and create one state for every value in that list.
        """
        states_data = validated_data.pop('states')
        queryset = State.objects.none()   # Creo un queryset vacío
        for state_data in states_data:
            State.objects.create(state=state_data)
            queryset |= State.objects.filter(state=state_data) # Agrego cada registro que se va creando en la iteración
        return queryset  # Devuelvo el queryset con (supuestamente) todos los datos creados.
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es renderizar la respuesta, pero el create no es el metodo para ello. Django Rest Framework, utiliza el metodo `to_represantation`, para personalizar tu respuesta

ejemplo

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    """Convert `username` to lowercase."""
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    ret['username'] = ret['username'].lower()
    return ret
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

Comment: Si, para renderizarlo eso es lo que me funcionó. El problema es que como debo crear más de una instancia en la consulta, no puedo enviarle muchas instancias al método to_representation. Me gustaria saber una forma en que le llegue al menos la lista con lo que envié (quitar el write_only por supuesto) y renderizarlo a partir de esa informacion.